# What is the difference between Ask Ubuntu and Super User?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/361525/how-to-shutdown-a-computer-on-the-lan-that-use-windows-os) I asked here on Ask Ubuntu was migrated to [Super User](https://superuser.com/) and I don't know what that is for?

Comment: this is not a forum. Look in the about section and you will understand. :-)

http://askubuntu.com/about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Ask Ubuntu and Super User are part of the Stack Exchange Network:

- Super User is for computer [enthusiasts and power users](https://superuser.com/faq).
- Ask Ubuntu is a questions and answers site for [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system))-related questions.

Ask Ubuntu only covers questions about *the Ubuntu operating system*. Whereas Superuser covers *Windows*, computer software, and computer hardware.